# Npm audit critical fix immer <=9.0.5

Tags: reactjs, npm

In my react project I have the following critical vulnerability when I run an npm audit:

```
immer  <=9.0.5
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in immer - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-33f9-j839-rf8h
Prototype Pollution in immer - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9qmh-276g-x5pj
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@5.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/immer
  react-dev-utils  0.4.0 - 12.0.0-next.60
  Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
  Depends on vulnerable versions of globby
  Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
  Depends on vulnerable versions of inquirer
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    react-scripts  >=0.8.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of eslint
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-watch-typeahead
    Depends on vulnerable versions of optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
    Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts
```

I know I'm supposed to update the immer version to a higher version and I have tried to do that but the critical vulnerability remains. What's weird is that when I look into the package.json I see the version being 9.0.6

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "latest",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "glob-parent": "^6.0.0",
    "immer": "^9.0.6",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "object-path": "^0.11.8",
    "react": "^15.7.0",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.4",
    "react-bootstrap-autosuggest": "latest",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "react-select": "^3.2.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "^6.0.0",
    "yargs-parser": "^13.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:$port"
}
```

In **package-lock json** I see these instances of immer:

```
"immer": {
  "version": "9.0.7",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/immer/-/immer-9.0.7.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-KGllzpbamZDvOIxnmJ0jI840g7Oikx58lBPWV0hUh7dtAyZpFqqrBZdKka5GlTwMTZ1Tjc/bKKW4VSFAt6BqMA=="
},

"react-dev-utils": {
      "version": "10.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/-/react-dev-utils-10.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-XxTbgJnYZmxuPtY3y/UV0D8/65NKkmaia4rXzViknVnZeVlklSh8u6TnaEYPfAi/Gh1TP4mEOXHI6jQOPbeakQ==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/code-frame": "7.8.3",
        "address": "1.1.2",
        "browserslist": "4.10.0",
        "chalk": "2.4.2",
        "cross-spawn": "7.0.1",
        "detect-port-alt": "1.1.6",
        "escape-string-regexp": "2.0.0",
        "filesize": "6.0.1",
        "find-up": "4.1.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "3.1.1",
        "global-modules": "2.0.0",
        "globby": "8.0.2",
        "gzip-size": "5.1.1",
        "immer": "1.10.0",
        "inquirer": "7.0.4",
        "is-root": "2.1.0",
        "loader-utils": "1.2.3",
        "open": "^7.0.2",
        "pkg-up": "3.1.0",
        "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.7",
        "recursive-readdir": "2.2.2",
        "shell-quote": "1.7.2",
        "strip-ansi": "6.0.0",
        "text-table": "0.2.0"
      },

"immer": {
  "version": "1.10.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/immer/-/immer-1.10.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-O3sR1/opvCDGLEVcvrGTMtLac8GJ5IwZC4puPrLuRj3l7ICKvkmA0vGuU9OW8mV9WIBRnaxp5GJh9IEAaNOoYg=="
},
```

Any idea how I can resolve this critical vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your package-lock.json there are two instances of immer. The version `9.0.7` in coming from your package.json but internally `react-dev-utils` also requires `"immer": "1.10.0",` hence you are getting issues. Try upgrading `react-scripts` package to latest as well(since `react-dev-utils` coming from it and hence old `immer` version), and then I believe, you'll be good to go. Please upvote as well if you find this helpful, else let me know.